# How to implement timed wake up in modernStandby state?

Tags: sleep

I triggered devSleep by closing the screen, but couldn't wake up on time!

In the normal state, the mouse movement +SendMessage can open the screen, but not after sleeping, and the timer did not wake up. Is there any good way? Why doesn't Microsoft provide an API to implement sleep Hibernate as easily as S3 S4?